# Why does one function work and other don't ? How is the mutability or immutability working here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a list as such `li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and a scale function as

```
def scale(data, factor):
    for j in range(len(data)):
        data[j] *= factor
```

Now if I pass `li` to `scale` function with a `factor = 2`, my list gets modified. That is the actual parameter gets changed here. So if i print `li` after executing the above function it gives `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]` and not the original one.

Another way scale function is implemented is as follows:-

```
def scale(data, factor):
    for val in data:
        val *= factor
```

Now if I execute `scale(li, 2)` then it doesn't modify the actual parameter. So `li` stays as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.
So my question is why does one modify the list and the other doesn't?
Has this got anything to do with mutability or immutability?

Comment: Val in that for loop is immutable

Comment: In first example list is passed as reference by default thusunderline data is modified. Whereas val is the local variable which has been updated locally for each value in the list. Does not affecting the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[j] *= factor` is the same as `data[j] = data[j] * factor` so you are modifying `data` object. This operation calls `__setitem__` method of list `data`, which puts the result of `data[j] * factor` into the corresponding position.

When you do `for val in data:` in `val` is stored a reference to an item in `data`. That item (object) doesn't not know anything about the list `data` it was taken from. You are now working only with the item itself, not the list which contains another reference to it (along with `val`).

`val *= factor` creates a new object (the result of the product) and puts a reference to it into variable `val`. `data` still contains a reference to the old object/value which was in `val` before the assignment.

See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140747/248296

Comment: In the link that you shared he has written that for mutable objects, both references will be same. Is it always so? Just a newbie in python.. So curious :)

Comment: "both references will be same" -- he said "both references refer to the same object"
Mutability is a matter of protocol. An object is mutable if any of its methods modifies the object in place,  no new object is created. If all the methods return a new object, the object is immutable.

Comment: so if i have a list as l1 = [1, 2, 3] and l2 = [1, 2, 3] then does that mean that both references l1 and l2 will point to same object since lists are mutable? Sorry to disturb you again, just clarifying my concepts.

Comment: no, these are two lists which are equal but are different objects (`id(l1) != id(l2)`).

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is the fact, that you use an index to access the list in the first example and store the result in the list directly. In the second example you store the result in a variable which is holding the value taken from the list.

You can think of `for val in data:` as a shorthand for:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    val = data[i]
```

Now changing `val` (through `val *= factor`) will not change `data` (Why should it?). And as this is, what your second example is doing, the `data` list is not modified.

On the other hand, when you do `data[i] *= factor`, you are actually modifying the list, because you store the result in `data[i]` instead of the "temporary" variable `val`.

You could simplify it further, and look at

```
data[0] = 1
```

and compare it to

```
val = data[0]
val = 1
```

It should be obvious why one of them changes `data` and one does not. Your loops do effectively the same things and therefor one changes `data` and one does not.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, the for loop creates a variable `val=1` (and so on). When you do `val = val * factor`, the value of val changes. However, this has no connection to the original `list[0]`. You are just changing a temporary variable `val`

On the first example however, you do `list[0] = list[0] * factor`, so the assignment is done to the list itself.

I wouldn't say that it's so much a matter of mutability/immutability here (the right hand of both assignments is the same, and multiplies an immutable object in both cases). Mutability would be an issue if, eg, in the second example, you were passing `val` instead of `data` to your function, and change its value. In that case, the original value would not change, because `val` would be immutable.

Answer (score 0):

The inplace operator...

```
x *= y
```

...is more or less equivalent to...

```
x = x * y
```

In particular, the result will be reassigned to `x`.

In your first example, you assign to `data[j]`, index access changes the value at index `j`. This mutates your list.

In your second example, the values from the list are assigned to `val`, the inline operator thus reassignes to `val`. This is not an index access, so the list is not mutated.

In other words, your second example behaves like this:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    # values from the list are assigned to val
    val = data[i]

    # A new value is assigned to val
    val = value * factor
```